# -webkit-linear-gradient causes banding in Chrome/Safari

Tags: google-chrome, css

The title prettymuch says it all. The first picture below is a screenshot when the whole page is about 8000 pixels tall, taken in the latest version of Chrome:

[image]

while this picture is for a different page (using the same CSS) which is about 800 pixels tall:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
  body{ 
     background-color: #f3ffff;
     margin:0px;
     background-image: url('/media/flourish.png'),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(
            top, 
           rgba(99, 173, 241, 1) 0px, 
           rgba(0, 255, 255, 0) 250px
        );

     background-image: url('/media/flourish.png'), 
        -moz-linear-gradient(
           top, 
           rgba(99, 173, 241, 1) 0px, 
           rgba(0, 255, 255, 0) 250px
        );


     background-image: url('/media/flourish.png'), 
        -o-linear-gradient(
           top, 
           rgba(99, 173, 241, 1) 0px, 
           rgba(0, 255, 255, 0) 250px
        );
     background-position: center top, center top;
     background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#63ADF1', endColorstr='#00000000')";
  }
```

The gradient is meant to cut off at 250px from the top of the page. The fact that the degree of banding seems to depend on the total height of the page is very strange: pages of heights in between these two (800px and 8000px) seem to have bands which are smaller than the first example but still noticeable.

Interestingly, I was previously using `-webkit-gradient('linear'...)` instead and that did not have the same problem; I only swapped over to `-webkit-linear-gradient` so it would fall in line with my `-moz` and `-o` gradients.

I haven't tried it on Safari, but the code above makes it work perfectly fine in Firefox and kind-of-work in Opera (the colors get messed up, but the gradient is still smooth). Nevermind IE, which i have given up on.

Has anyone else seen this before?

Update: This happens on my Mac's Chrome/Safari too, but the bands are about 1/3 the size of the bands shown in the top image, for the exact same page. The banding is identical in both OSX Chrome and OSX Safari.

1/3 the size is still noticeable, but not quite so jarring. The actual page is at http://www.techcreation.sg/page/web/Intro%20to%20XTags/, if you want to see for yourself in some other browser. The CSS is "inline" css compiled in-browser using less.js.

Comment: I can't look at the problem because your link isn't currently working (`KeyError at /page/web/Intro to XTags/`). However, this appears to be a WebKit bug. Stack Overflow might be able to provide a workaround, but it can't fix the bug. You should file a bug report, if you haven't done so already, here: https://bugs.webkit.org/

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my solution below?

Comment: Ended up using that; thanks =)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like a webkit bug.  I came up with the work-around below, tested on the latest Chrome and FF.  In short, you'll position a div containing the background behind your main content.  I also added a few styles to make IE happier.

Given this HTML:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        ...
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background">bgdiv</div>
    <div class="content_pane">
        <div class="titlebar">Leave a Comment!</div>
        <div class="comment">Your Comment.</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Combined with this stylesheet:

```
    body{
        background-color: #f3ffff;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin:0px;
    }
    .background {
        height: 250px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;  /* could use fixed if you like. */
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: -10;

        background-image:
            -webkit-linear-gradient(top,
                rgba(99, 173, 241, 1) 0px,
                rgba(0, 255, 255, 0) 250px
            );
        background-image:
            -moz-linear-gradient(top,
                rgba(99, 173, 241, 1) 0px,
                rgba(0, 255, 255, 0) 250px
            );
        background-image:
            -o-linear-gradient(top,
                rgba(99, 173, 241, 1) 0px,
                rgba(0, 255, 255, 0) 250px
            );
        background-image:
            -ms-linear-gradient(top,
                rgba(99,173,241,1) 0%,
                rgba(0,255,255,0) 250px
            ); /* IE10+ */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#63adf1', endColorstr='#0000ffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        background-image:
            linear-gradient(top,
                rgba(99,173,241,1) 0%,
                rgba(0,255,255,0) 250px
            ); /* W3C */
        background-position: center top, center top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
    }
    .content_pane {
        background: white;
        border: 1px dotted white;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        font-family: arial, sans;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 6em auto 5em;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .titlebar {
        background: #3f7cdb;
        color: white;
        font-family: arial, sans;
        padding: .25em 2ex .25em;
    }
    .comment {
        padding: 1em;
    }
```

It should come out looking like this, regardless of window size:

[image: Chrome image]

Comment: I removed `-image` and still works, so why did you add that ?

Comment: I think it came from the css gradient generator I used.  Didn't bother to change it.  Looks like it is a bit more specific than just "background:".

Comment: Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j8y3q5t0/ if anyone is interested in seeing a demo.

Comment: This seems to only "work" if the div is over a certain height. If you set the height to `50px` instead of `250px` you will still see the banding. (At least in Chrome 44 for Linux)

I think the bug just becomes unnoticeable when it is stretched out further.

Answer (score 4):

Your demo link does not work but i did some tests and it worked fine for me using Chrome when you add width/height of 100% to the body/html elements, like so:

```
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/CHxuV/)

You can try that or you can just declare a header/logo piece where you can add the starting gradient and just add the ending gradient to the body of your css so it blends in correctly, like so:

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    background-color: #f3ffff;
    margin:0px;
    height:10000px;
}

.header {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/stuttgart/32/premium.png'),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(99, 173, 241, 1), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0));

    background-image: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/stuttgart/32/premium.png'),
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); 

    background-image: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/stuttgart/32/premium.png'), 
    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(99, 173, 241, 1) 0px, rgba(0, 255, 255, 0) 250px
    );

    background-image: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/stuttgart/32/premium.png'), 
    -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(99, 173, 241, 1) 0px, rgba(0, 255, 255, 0) 250px);
    background-position: center top, center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
    background-size:auto;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#63ADF1', endColorstr='#00000000')";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    content
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/Mp3hE/)

**Friendly note:** For anybody looking for the issue you can see it happening here in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/skJGG/

Comment: Adding height and width to body and html works indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Chrome has some bugs when using the rgba() values. I tried with normal hex values and it seems to fix the problem for me.

Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JoseFaeti/VNX9w/17/) if it fix it for you also.

**Edit**

Looks like the problem is in the 250px limit because it only appears when that is set.

I didn't manage to come up with a better solution than [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/JoseFaeti/VNX9w/23/).

Overlapping a div with the gradient you like, 250px tall. Then you can have the page as tall as you want because the div will always be 250px tall.

Answer (score 0):

Webkit render `-webkit-gradient('linear'...)` and `webkit-linear-gradient` in the same way. The problem is with your multiple backgrounds. I had same issue and I was ended with two different elements on top of each other and then giving a background to each of them. Something like:

```
<body>
 <div class="body-overlay"<div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{-webkit-linear-gradient(...)}
    .body-overlay{background:url('blah.png')}
```

I think this happens because the image have fixed amount of pixels

Comment: that didn't seem to work; i took out the flourish entirely and i still get the banding. Given that it depends on the height of the whole page, i'm thinking it's something to do with the way the gradient is calculated bugging up.

Comment: That was all I knew. wish you found the bug

Answer (score 0):

instead of using background-image, try using this(background) -

```
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#63adf1), color-stop(53%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* feel free to play with the % values to get what you are looking for */
```

and also use hex values always. But from an UX prospective it would be better to use as in image(since you are loading an image anyway) and you won't have to worry about cross browser compatibility.

Comment: The main reason I wanted to use RBGA was for the transparency; The color changes from blue to teal and from opaque to transparent, over an off-white background, effectively giving a very pleasant blue -> teal -> white gradient that would be somewhat annoying to generate manually. I will try using translucent .png images to see how it turns out.

Comment: yes i'd suggest a transparent png (keeping in mind it wont work in IE6) coz RGBA wont work in all browser versions. But try the above code and see if it stops the banding coz if i remember right i had got the same issue.. when i used it in background image...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `background-size: auto, 250px 250px;` — `auto` for first image and 250px for your gradient.

When you don't need a gradient image so big that it would cover whole page it's best to limit it's size. Besides rendering problems with big images, I think that it's better for the browser's performance.

So, you example would look like http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/phPSb/ (blindcoded, couldn't reproduce the problem though).

Answer (score 0):

In any strange situation try to use:

```
transform: translateZ(10px);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case was the height of the body. Try the following:

```
body {
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    ...
}
```