# Background gradient breaks in Chrome when element is taller than about 32,000 pixels

Tags: css, google-chrome, background, gradient, linear-gradients

I have a case where a user is allowed to see the entire contents of a table that's normally paginated, and in rare instances the element gets very long. In Chrome, the background gradient falls apart, rendering as solid black and various other blocks, when the height of the element exceeds around 32,000 pixels.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hBm4C/1/

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
    color-stop(0%,#ccc), color-stop(100%,#f5f5f5));
```

I see a similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233649/webkit-linear-gradient-causes-banding-in-chrome-safari) from 2011, but this seems different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is kind of peculiar and clearly down to a bug in Chrome

If you remove the border from your styling it miraculously works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/hBm4C/2/

```
.gradient-tall {
width: 150px;
height: 35000px;
display: inline-block;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ccc), color-stop(100%,#f5f5f5));
vertical-align: top;
```

}

To have the gradient and a border as well can be achieved by using box-shadow:

```
.gradient-tall {
    width: 150px;
    height: 35000px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #777;
    background:#ccc;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(#ccc 1%, #f5f5f5 99%);
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hBm4C/3/

Comment: Very interesting. It fixes the gradient in my case, also. I'll try putting the background on a child element.

Comment: You can create a fake border of sorts using box-shadow also. Will add that to the answer.

Comment: +1 for finding a work-around. If you need a border, you could try using `outline` instead; that seems to work where `border` doesn't (I just checked in the fiddle and it's fine). `box-shadow` might also be an option, although it's more complex than `outline`. Alternatively, use a `:before` or `:after` selector to create a pseudo-element for your `border`.

Comment: Note that unlike borders, outlines and box shadows do not affect box sizing and layout in any way, which may or may not be problematic.

Comment: Unfortunately my element already has box-shadow. I'm having success putting the background gradient on a child element, however. Thanks for sleuthing this!